# How to size a popup programmatically in Swift without storyboard?

Tags: swift, popup

I am trying to present a popup view, but I am having trouble sizing it properly. I have the following code which present my popup but preferredContentSize does not work. View always come full screen which is not what I want. How do I size the popup properly?

```
func presentPopup() {
        let popupVC = MyPopupViewController()
        popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        popupVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        // the following does not size the view, always come up full screen
        popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200) 
        present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to achieve something similar to the following.

[image]

Please note: I don't use storyboard and I'm looking for a solution without using or instantiating storyboard.

Comment: Post an image what you try to achieve.

Comment: @SagarChauhan something similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRt9p.png

Comment: Please check my answer. You can change height / width of controller as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a better way to achieve my goal. Instead of sizing the popup in main view I moved the sizing logic to the popUpView itself. Here is the final code.

```
func presentPopup() {
        let popupVC = MyPopupViewController()
        popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

MyPopupViewController

```
class MyPopupViewController: UIViewController {
    // UI elements for popup will be added to popupBox view
    let popupBox: UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        setupViews()

    }


func setupViews() { 
     view.addSubview(popupBox)

     // autolayout constraint for popupBox
        popupBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        popupBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        popupBox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        popupBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following code to instantiate your presenter controller and setup required configuration.

```
let popupVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPopoverVC")
popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

let presentationController = MyControllerPresentAsPopover.configurePresentation(forController: popupVC)
presentationController.sourceView = sender
presentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [.any]
present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then create class named as `MyControllerPresentAsPopover` which have implemented delegate method of `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`. See code below:

```
class MyControllerPresentAsPopover : NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    private static let sharedInstance = MyControllerPresentAsPopover()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }

    static func configurePresentation(forController controller : UIViewController) -> UIPopoverPresentationController {
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let presentationController = controller.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController
        presentationController.delegate = MyControllerPresentAsPopover.sharedInstance
        return presentationController
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I guess I should have made my self clearer. By programatically I meant no storyboard. I always delete the storyboard file from my projects and therefore there is no sender to work with. Would you be able to revise your answer without storyboard?

Comment: @Ali_C, you can use your view controller instead of storyboard directly.

Comment: There is no required to have view controller with storyboard, if you have created it programatically then you can use it.